# What determines how much XP I get for extra Medi-Gel?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When picking up Medi-Gel when you're full, you get XP (rather than credits, like in ME2). What determines how much XP I get? I've received anywhere from 100XP to 300XP for a pack during the same mission without any rhyme or reason to what is causing the discrepancy.

Is there any relation to my maximum carrying capacity? My max health? Or is each Medi-Gel station simply hard coded to give you a certain amount of XP if you're full, regardless? I'm currently playing on Hardcore, so knowing if difficulty affects this would also be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Difficulty affects the amount of XP per Medigel as well. Numbers from Coalesced.bin.

Insanity - 150XP
Hardcore - 100XP
Normal - 50XP
Easy - 25XP
Casual - 25XP

Medkits contain 2 Medigel, Med Stations may contain more. Only excess Medigel will be converted to XP. If you have 7/8 Medigel on Normal and open a Medkit, you will gain +1 Medigel and +50 XP. With 8/8 you will gain +100 XP.

Comment: I'm playing on Hardcore currently. You apparently get twice the XP for Medi-Gel when you're full, which I always am. How would that account for me getting 300XP for some Medi-Gel dispensers?

Comment: As mike1987 said above, some dispensers have multiple Medigels, and the XP adds up.

Comment: However, if you do indeed get double xp for being full on medi-gel, that doesn't explain how I'd end up with 300XP. I should get either 200XP (for 1 dose) or 400XP (for 2 doses) while playing on Hardcore.

Comment: I wasn't aware you get 2x exp for being full? I thought if you weren't full you simply get medigel instead of exp.

Comment: I just tested. Only excess medigel will give you XP. At no point is it 2x XP. You might be seeing "twice the XP" since most medkits give 2 medigels, and some give 3. On Insanity most medkits give 2 medigels or 300 XP.

Comment: What happens then if you're at 7/8 and you hit a Medi-Gel station with 2 in it?

Comment: Tested just now on Normal. With 6 Medigel, I got +2 Medigel. With 8 /8 Medigel, I got +100 XP. Will test 7.

Comment: 7/8 on Normal gives +1 Medigel and +50 XP.

Comment: Great, can you edit your findings into your base enter? I'll accept then. :)

Answer (score 7):

Some Medigel boxes give you two or maybe even three Medigel, which would account for the extra experience. That's the only reason I could think of when I was playing.

Comment: Do you have any numbers for how each difficulty affects how much XP you get per Medi-gel?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I don't have them at present, but if I get time I will start some new saves, compare the difference & let you know.

Answer (score 3):

I think different stations give different amounts of medi-gel, so maybe for each medi-gel over the limit you go, you get 100 exp with it.